# Looping on Text boxes included in ajax Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have 20 Text boxes and i want to take their value by loop on each one ,
the problem is all of text boxes are included in Ajax Tab Container , so when i use below code it gives me error :

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

It can`t find the control because it's on tab, [image]

if I try to use below code away from tab container it works fine

```
string TicketIDLoop = "";
for (int MutiVar = 1; MutiVar <= 20; MutiVar++)
{

 ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
 TextBox mpTextBox;
 mpContentPlaceHolder =
   (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
 if (mpContentPlaceHolder != null)
 {
     mpTextBox =
         (TextBox)mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TTIDTextBox" + MutiVar.ToString());
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mpTextBox.Text) == false)
     {

         TicketIDLoop = mpTextBox.Text;
         //MessageBox.Show(mpTextBox.Text.ToString());

         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZainJTAConnectionString_96"].ConnectionString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.CommandText = "[JTA_Schema].[SP_WFM_Update]";

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@UpdateID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TicketIDLoop;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@Specialist", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["Session_UserName"];
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@resoultion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ClosingResolutionDropDownList.SelectedValue.Trim();
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@WFMComment", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CommentVar;

         cmd.Connection = con;

         try
         {
             con.Open();

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             throw ex;
         }

         finally
         {
             con.Close();
             con.Dispose();
         }
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is no attached picture; looks like this is an WebForms project. If the input elements are in an AJAX controls, you will likely not be able to access their values until a postback occurs.

Comment: indeed it is a web form and the error is :"object reference not set to an instance of an object" ...... it can`t find the control because it`s on tab

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle are you calling the code you posted ?

Comment: i put it on button , the page load well just when i press on the button and it gets to this part it raises the error

Comment: how i refer to text boxes which include in tab container which include in content holder ?